# Limit of a function tending to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $F(t)$ is twice differentiable at $x$ and $$G(h)=\max_{t\in(0,h)}\left[\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x-t)}{2t}-F''(x)\right],$$ where $x$ is fixed; then how can we show that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}G(h)=0$.

Comment: There are abstract duplicates of this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/146023/264) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/123206/264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x-t)}{t}=\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x)}{t}+\frac{F'(x-t)-F'(x)}{-t}.$$

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed very useful! I started with the obvious one, then tried to give a little more.

Comment: You removed the $t$, I removed my comment. A pity, this equation would have allowed me to show (no, I won't tell ;-)

Comment: @Kns: I was being too indirect. Have changed the hint, added primes. Note that each part is related to the derivative of $F'$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $h\to0$ means $t\to0$, so
$$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}G(h) = \lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x-t)}{2t}-F''(x)\right]$$
apply l'Hôpital's rule，we can get
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x-t)}{2t}-F''(x)\right] = \lim_{t \to 0}\left[\frac{F''(x+t)+F''(x-t)}{2}-F''(x)\right] = 0$$

ps: your tags include real analysis, I assume $x\in \mathbf{R^{n}}$, although real analysis isn't only about real numbers. I dou't know if l'Hôpital's rule can apply under other situation.

Comment: (This was my first intent, too: L'Hospital) I've a doubt here: in the RHS the $\,t's\,$ disappeared while you still are taking the limit when $\,t\to 0\,$ , but this is equivalent to plug $\,t=0\,$ after applying L'Hospital, which is justified if $\,F''\,$ is continuous in $\,x\,$, something we can't know...

Comment: If I recall correctly, L'Hospital does not require the derivative to be continuous(namely $F''$ here), the existent of the derivative in the area is enough

Comment: Indeed it doesn't, but you require it to put $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F''(x+t)+F''(x-t)}{2}=\frac{F''(x)+F''(x)}{2}$$which is what in fact you did, or, of course, justify otherwise this equality.

Comment: oh, you are right, my fault, thanks. edit it. And then I get what you meant.... thinking now

Comment: seems it is not appropriate here. Thanks for the reminding

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By definition

$$ F''(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F'(x+h)-F'(x)}{h}$$

Couple this with [Andre's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/156106/7476)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\,t\in(,h)\,$ , we have that  $\,h\to 0\Longrightarrow t\to 0\,$ , so:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x-t)}{2t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{F'(x+t)-F'(x)}{t}+\frac{F'(x-t)-F'(x)}{-t}\right]$$
and you get what you want since we know $\,F''(x)\,$ exists, so the limit defining this second derivative exists.