# Second Order Numerical Differentiation

Tags: numerical-methods

If we take the central difference twice we get $$\frac{f(x+2h)+f(x-2h)-2f(x)}{4h^2}$$

It is said that taking the forward difference and then the central difference is equal, but I do not get the same expression

$$\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)-f(x)-f(x-h)}{4h^2}$$

Comment: They are equal in the limit of $h \rightarrow 0$ if $f \in C^2$, but are definitely not equal for finite values of $h$. Where does this phrase come from?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123206